# Regex to find the starting line and column of the function module body

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, my code is something like this:

```
    (function t(p1,p2,...) //comment
      {
line 2,column 1
```

I think a regex could do the job, but I don't know how to get the end of the regex match to get the position result: line 2,column 1.

I just need to find the end position for the match `.(.function.(.).{` where `.` means anything.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What about `(function(){} function(){}`? Or `var txt = "(This functions as blah.)"; function(){ ...`? This matches your "definition" of *`.(.function.(.).{` where `.` means anything*. Regex is not sufficient to parse JavaScript.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to parse code, but you may have sth. like this in mind: https://regex101.com/r/nTvbp3/1

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish. In the Help Center (https://stackoverflow.com/help) you will find instructions about how to make your questions clearer, so our community will be able to help you.

Comment: Is the immediately invoked function expression set as the value of a variable? Or are you trying to parse an entire JavaScript file?

Comment: What is the real goal of what you need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR;

This part of the code is used to get the function starts:

```
var regex1 = /\s*\(\s*function\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\{/;
```

Means:

- any whitespace before and after `(` is accepted
- then look for "function" string
- then again any whitespace character is accepted
- look for `(` and until the `)` character or none, loop chars
- then look for the `)` char after previous loop ends
- then any whitespace character or none is accepted again (line breaks also accepted)
- but look for `{` character in the end.

---

This is the part of my [karma-code-reporter](https://github.com/tpaksu/karma-code-reporter) module for jasmine testing. I used this to parse the jasmine definition files. `content` is the file content array splitted by line breaks.

```
/**
   * calculates the jasmine formatted test file method bounds
   * @param {array} content: line by line splitted test code content
   * @returns {array} bounds of the methods separated by groups, specs and de-constructors.
   */
  this.findBounds = function (content) {
    // prepare the output object
    var bounds = { groups: [], cases: [], deconst: [] };
    // loop each line
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      // prepare regular expressions for describe, it and before/afterEach blocks
      var regex1 = /describe\s*\(.+?,\s*function\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\{/;
      var regex2 = /it\s*\(.+?,\s*function\s*\(/;
      var regex3 = /(?:beforeEach|afterEach)\s*\(\s*function\s*\(/;
      // if it's a match for "describe"
      if ((regex1.exec(content[i]) || []).length > 0) {
        // push the bounds for this block
        bounds.groups.push([i, this.findEndLine(content, i)]);
      }
      // if it's a match for "it"
      else if ((regex2.exec(content[i]) || []).length > 0) {
        // push the bounds for this block
        bounds.cases.push([i, this.findEndLine(content, i)]);
      }
      // if it's a match for "beforeEach" or "afterEach"
      else if ((regex3.exec(content[i]) || []).length > 0) {
        // push the bounds for this block
        bounds.deconst.push([i, this.findEndLine(content, i)]);
      }
    }
    // return the calculated bounds
    return bounds;
  };

  /**
   * Finds the end bracket for a given start bracket on the content
   * @param {string} content    : line by line split test code content
   * @param {integer} startLine : the line number containing the start bracket
   */
  this.findEndLine = function (content, startLine) {
    // find the start bracket position
    var match = /\bfunction\s*\([^)]*\)\s*({)/i.exec(content[startLine]);
    var pos = match[0].length + match.index - 1;
    // prepare a stack for the brackets
    var $stack = [];
    // loop each character
    while (startLine < content.length) {
      while (pos < content[startLine].length) {
        // read the char
        var read = content[startLine][pos];
        // if read char is a start bracket
        if (read == "{") {
          // push it to the array
          $stack.push("{");
        } else if (read == "}") {
          // if read char is a closing bracket, read from the stack
          var val = $stack.pop();
          if (val == "{") {
            // if the closing bracket matches with an opening bracket
            if ($stack.length == 0) {
              // if there are no brackets left, return the end line
              return startLine;
            }
          } else {
            // the brackets are not correctly positioned, return error
            return -1;
          }
        }
        // go to the next char
        pos++;
      }
      // go to the next line
      startLine++;
      // reset position
      pos = 0;
    }
    // if this line is reached, there must be an error.
    return -1;
  }
```

Taken from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpaksu/karma-code-reporter/master/index.js

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept the answer. You show me the way. +1